# How to keep refetching until a condition is met react query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

Hi I was wondering how do i keep polling an api until a condition is met with react query.
I have a query function that makes a call to the api and  returns the response data so for example it it will return an object like this

```
{
name: string
age: number
job: string
}
```

I want to be to keep polling until I get a specific name for example.

```
  const fetchQuery = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['fetchQuery'],
    queryFn: fetchApi,
    enabled: false,
  });
```

I see the refetchInterval option but unsure how to access the data to be able to do something like

```
refetchInterval(query){
 if(query.name === 'my-name'){return false;}
 return 3000;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`query` is an instance of the `Query` class, which holds `state`. The TypeScript types should tell you what's available. In your case, you'd want:

```
refetchInterval(query){
 if(query.state.data?.name === 'my-name'){return false;}
 return 3000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the queryClient and invalidate the query until your condition is met.

### Example

```
import queryClient from 'your-react-query-config'

const queryHook = () => {
    const { data } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['fetchQuery'],
        queryFn: fetchApi,
    });

    if (data.name !== 'my-name') {
        // Condition is not met, let's re-fetch the query
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(['fetchQuery'])
    }

    return { data } 
}
```

https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/reference/QueryClient#queryclientinvalidatequeries

Answer (score -1):

I think [useInfiniteQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/reference/useInfiniteQuery) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: useInfiniteQuery is for pagination